# Is it any IP based remote access software avalaible?

Tags: windows, linux, offline, remote-access, remote-desktop

I want software which is work like IP_tux or ipmsg, but that software can be able to access remote PC from LAN network.

If I have 20 PC in my organization. and I want to fix some task from another PC as if I were working on the remote machine which is in LAN but both computers are not connected to Internet.

I want software that can remotely access another computer without Internet. [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) would fit this description, but it requires Internet access.

Comment: Any software can do that – as long as both computers are connected to the same LAN (or the LANs they're connected to are connected to each other). Your question is a bit unclear on what kind of "task" you want "to fix", and what OS is involved. I e.g. use the `ssh` command on Linux to start a process on a remote computer.

Comment: @Izzy I want any software which can do like team viewer. but team viewer required Internet and I want software that can be done by only through LAN wire.

Comment: Ah, now I see (just updated your question to make that clearer – hope my edit fits). Raises the question: What OS on which end? Depending on that, answers go in the direction [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).

Comment: Is the question "How to access the desktop GUI of another computer while on a LAN without involving any coordinating server from the Internet?" ?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes

Comment: @lzzy I want both options Windows as well as Linux if possible. Also I want access windows PC from linux and Linux PC from windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've used TeamViewer over LAN before.
Here's a [official guide.](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only/ta-p/4618)